# how to pause timer in another activity in android

Tags: android, timer, tabs

I have a tabActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
          @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            Resources ressources = getResources(); 
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

            // Android tab
            Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), AndroidActivity.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Android")
                .setIndicator("android", ressources.getDrawable( R.drawable.icon_android_config )).setContent(intentAndroid);

            // Apple tab
            Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), AppleActivity.class);
            TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Apple")
                .setIndicator("apple", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_apple_config)).setContent(intentApple);

            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }}
```

this is my timer:

```
 public class AndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener  {

  public static Timer timer1 = new Timer();

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
  timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                     {
                      public void run() 
                      {  

//do some thing
                      }
                     });
                   }
                }, 0, 4000);

}
```

I want pause timer1 in this activity:

```
public class AppleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

This is my problem that when I change tab in program ,program didn't call 'onCreate' ,and I don't know where I pause the timer and How I pause my timer . 
(I want when  android tab is active , timer1 start and when apple tab is active, timer1 stop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This

```
     public class AndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener  {

      Timer timer1;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.map);

    }
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            timer1.cancel():
        }
        @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onResume();
 timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                             {
                              public void run() 
                              {  

        //do some thing
                              }
                             });
                           }
                        }, 0, 4000);

        }
            }
```

Comment: This is my problem that when I change tab in program ,program didn't call 'onCreate' . program call  onCreate only one time

Comment: my full code is very big.  I want when user select android tab (AndroidActivity ) timer1 start  and when User select apple tab (AppleActivity) , timer1 stop.

Comment: use this u must know activity lifecyle before implementing your application efficiently

Comment: thanks , it is true , but how can start timer1 again  when user select androidActivity again

Comment: this have AndroidRuntime  Exception

Comment: this has AndroidRuntime Exception , I think it is because of runOnUiThread

Comment: I put timer1 = new Timer(); in onResume and it works. thanks alot

Comment: actually the timer which was started in on create was running in a thread so it has to be stopped so new Timer() should be created in onResume()

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

AndroidActivity.timer1

it is `public static` object so you can get where ever you need. and one more thing Timer class not have `pause()` method. so you have to use `cancel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep your `Activity` alive? While navigating from `AndroidActivity` to `AppleActivity` ideally you should stop the timer in say `onPause`.

In any `Activity` you have timer try to use this:

**AndroidActivity:**

```
public void destroyTimer() {
    if (timer != null) {
        isTimerCancelled = true;
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    destroyTimer();
    // do other stuffs
}
```